# Is there a way to identify an unknown jms object that is deserialisable?

Tags: java, spring, jms, ibm-mq

So you find an exception in your logs:

```
Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
com.company.eq.mo.app.exception.DefaultMessageListenerException: Failed to handle message.; nested exception is com.company.eq.mo.app.exception.DefaultMessageListenerException: This message does not contain a recognised java object; nested exception is javax.jms.MessageFormatException: MQJMS1061: Unable to deserialize object the class name to find out anymore info about the message:
```

The message is Deserialisable and you can't get and print the object out at runtime:

```
    Object object = ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject();
                object.getClass();
```

Because it does not exist in your class path.

Is there any other way of getting the class/object name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own parser for Java [Object Serialization Stream Protocol](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html), but for most practical purposes you do need to have all serialized classes available in the class path.